# knockout observable array computed

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I am trying to implement a simple 'toString' function for an `observableArray`.

When using this code which seems the most appropriate to me

```javascript
var viewModel = {

  name: ko.observable('test'),
  arr: ko.observableArray(['item1']),

  third: ko.computed(function(){

    return this.arr().join();
  })
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I **get a  this.arr is not a function** error

Why is this happening?

If I run it like this everything is ok.

```javascript
var viewModel = {

  name: ko.observable('test'),
  arr: ko.observableArray(['item1']),

  third: function(){

    return this.arr().join();
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

If I use the second approach, will I get the correct arr contents? Does the third variable get updated every time an item is added/removed from arr?

https://jsfiddle.net/zek2kz2b/5/

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/zek2kz2b/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that `this` in your computed isn't the view model so it doesn't have an `arr` method.

You need to provide your computed with the `this` context to use when it's invoked. You can do this by passing the view model a second parameter in your `ko.computed` call.

But because you're creating your view model as a plain object, you don't have the view model to pass in at the time you're calling `ko.computed`. So create your view model as a constructor function instead:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this; // Capture the view model as self to simplify things
  self.name = ko.observable('test'),
  self.arr = ko.observableArray(['item1']),
  self.third = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.arr().join();
  }, self); // We now have the view model available to pass here
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Another way to do this is to simply reference the `self` reference to the view model in the computed:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable('test'),
  self.arr = ko.observableArray(['item1']),
  self.third = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.arr().join();
  });
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```